# Android Single Instance of a Fragment

Tags: android

Is there a way that when we use `ft.addToBackStack(null);` we only add a single instance to the BackStack? Adding multiple instances of the same fragment to the Back Stack creates a clutter when the user presses the Back Button?

Comment: you have always a singe instance of the BackStack

Comment: Meaning in a given Fragment Transaction, calling ft.replace with the same fragment and then calling addToBackStack(null) would not add multiple fragment to the backstack ?

Answer (score 3):

You could try setting a string to the addToBackStack method. Ex

```
ft.addToBackStack("fragmentA");
```

Later then, if you are coing to insert that same fragment again. You do this before adding it to the layout.

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack("fragmentA", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(java.lang.String, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: He will NOT keep single instances in this case