# How to save state of fragment in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm using google navigation drawer library from the following link...
https://github.com/Arasthel/GoogleNavigationDrawerMenu

See code below:

```
    mDrawer.setOnNavigationSectionSelected(new GoogleNavigationDrawer.OnNavigationSectionSelected() {
        @Override
        public void onSectionSelected(View v, int i, long l) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                // fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new NewsFragment();

                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new TransferFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new BlogsFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new FixturesFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new BestXIFragment();
                break;
            case 6:
                fragment = new FeedFragment();

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main, fragment).commit();

            } else {
                // error in creating fragment
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
            }
        }
    });
```

My fragments are using async task and whenever I switch between these fragments the async task is loading again.

So How can I save the state of the fragment?

Comment: my guess is that you need to use the Fragment Backstack in a fashion similar to the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652071/android-single-instance-of-a-fragment

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new fragment every time you can keep an array of fragments and just return the same object:

```
mDrawer.setOnNavigationSectionSelected(new GoogleNavigationDrawer.OnNavigationSectionSelected() {

Fragment[] fragments ={new HomeFragment(),new NewsFragment(),  new TransferFragment(), new BlogsFragment(),new FixturesFragment() , new BestXIFragment(),new FeedFragment()};
 @Override

    public void onSectionSelected(View v, int i, long l) {

        if (fragment[i] != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main, fragments[i]).commit();

        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: inside fragments before starting asych task just check if it's running

Comment: post one of the fragments where you execute an asynch task

Comment: View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container,
    false);
  
  getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
  mFadingActionBarHelper = new FadingActionBarHelper(actionBar,
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_bg));
  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .add(R.id.container, new ListViewFragment()).commit();
  }
  return rootView;

Comment: And ListViewFragment have async task